# Solved: Multiplying the result of a SUM() on one table by the result of a COUNT() from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to multiply the sum computed in one table by the count of values found in another table linked to it.

I have a table with entries like this:

```
Table_A
Id
SubId
Start
Stop
```

For each Id there can be several SubId. The Id is linked through a whole series of other tables to a second table which basically looks like this:

```
Table_B
Id
Val
```

Id in Table_B can occur from one to multiple times.

The idea is that I want to mulitply the result of the sum of time spans found in Table_A for each SubId by the count of distinct Val found in Table_B by linking it through the Id.

I already have the sum of time spans from Table_A like this (I'm no developper so it might be very shoddy code, I apologize in advance):

```sql
SELECT SUM(duration) FROM (
  SELECT (mod_stop - mod_start) AS duration FROM (
    SELECT
      (CASE
        WHEN date_start < '@begin' THEN '@begin'
        ELSE date_start
      END) AS mod_start,
      (CASE
        WHEN date_stop > '@end' THEN '@end'
        WHEN date_stop = '0' THEN '@end'
        ELSE date_stop
      END) AS mod_stop
    FROM table_a
    WHERE (
      state = 'Launching' OR
      state = 'Running' OR
      state = 'Finishing'
    )
    AND table_a_id IN (
      SELECT
      DISTINCT(table_a_id)
      FROM table_a
      WHERE
        (to_timestamp(date_start), to_timestamp(date_stop)) OVERLAPS (to_timestamp('@begin'), to_timestamp('@end'))
      AND
        (state = 'Running' OR state = 'Launching' OR state = 'Finishing')
      AND
        NOT date_stop = '0'
    )
  ) AS t
) AS d
;
```

This works but I now need to multiply each duration by the number of Val associated to it's Id and I can't work out how to do this.

I thought having another `AND ... IN` clause in the `WHERE` with all the table linking mechanisms returning the individual Val count would do it but the query does not return anything despite running for over an hour whereas without it it returns in approximately ten minutes (there is no index on date_* and Table_A is several tens of million records long which explains why it is so slow) so I fear I might have got something wrong.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Not relevant for your question, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`. And inside a sub-query used for an IN condition it's also unnecessary

Comment: Yes, thank you for the important precision, I write it like that so that I remember what column was relevant for the `distinct` but it's just a personal (bad) habit, it's good if people don't get wrong impressions from my code :+1:

Comment: Well, **all** columns in the SELECT list are relevant for the distinct

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use CTEs? In one CTE get what you want from Table_A, in another get what you want from Table_B and then in your final SELECT join the two CTEs together and perform whatever calculation you want?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments posted and what I managed to find I've cobbled a solution together. It might be crude but it works. I build a temp table whose values I use to build a CTE. Feel free to comment if you think this can be done better.

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TEMP TABLE my_jsl ON COMMIT DROP AS
  SELECT job_id, job_state, mod_start, mod_stop, duration FROM (
    SELECT job_id, job_state, mod_start, mod_stop, mod_stop - mod_start duration FROM (
      SELECT job_id, job_state,
        (CASE
          WHEN date_start < :my_begin THEN :my_begin
          ELSE date_start
        END) AS mod_start,
        (CASE
          WHEN date_stop > :my_end THEN :my_end
          WHEN date_stop = '0' THEN :my_end
          ELSE date_stop
        END) AS mod_stop
      FROM job_state_logs 
      WHERE (
        job_state = 'Launching' OR
        job_state = 'Running' OR
        job_state = 'Finishing'
      )
      AND job_state_log_id IN (
        SELECT
        DISTINCT(job_state_log_id)
        FROM job_state_logs
        WHERE
          (to_timestamp(date_start), to_timestamp(date_stop)) OVERLAPS (to_timestamp(:my_begin), to_timestamp(:my_end))
        AND
          (job_state = 'Running' OR job_state = 'Launching' OR job_state = 'Finishing')
        AND
          NOT date_stop = '0'
      )
    ) AS job_temp_log
  ) AS job_log
;
WITH my_jr AS (
    SELECT COUNT(a.resource_id) jrc, j.job_id 
    FROM assigned_resources a 
    INNER JOIN moldable_job_descriptions m ON m.moldable_id = a.moldable_job_id 
    INNER JOIN jobs j ON j.assigned_moldable_job = m.moldable_id 
    WHERE j.job_id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT(job_id) FROM my_jsl
    )
    GROUP BY j.job_id
),
my_surf AS (
    SELECT my_jr.job_id, my_jsl.duration, my_jr.jrc, (my_jsl.duration * my_jr.jrc) AS surface 
    FROM my_jr, my_jsl 
    WHERE my_jr.job_id = my_jsl.job_id
)
SELECT SUM(surface) job_surface FROM my_surf
;
COMMIT;
;
```